# How get File from web service for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-services

i'm new to iPhone programming and web service too.
I'm trying to get a file from a Rest web service written with c#, the service return a byte array, the file is 15Mb.
I've try to many ways to get the file but if i get the file inside an XML response, i need to parse with NSXMLParser that make my application crash because alloc a string in memory and it also make the file bigger and i also need to convert on base 64.

How can i get the file without XML response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution.
When i get the file, that is content in the node of the XML response, i save it on disk.
Then with a NSFileHandle i jump after XML header and start to read the file with a while.
I read 1MB each time, convert to Base64 and then write it to disk with another NSFileHandle.

I hope that is usefull for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

How about just putting a URL to the file in the response, then using HTTP or FTP to retrieve the actual file?

Comment: I prefer to pass trough the web service.